# Compiling libpq with iOS SDK 4.2

Tags: postgresql, ios, compilation, ios-4.2, libpq

I'm trying to compile again the libpq for arm and i386 with the iOS SDK 4.2.

I did last year for SDK3.x without any problems.

Now, when I want to create the fat binary file with two files, I'm getting this error:

```
specifed architecture type (arm) for file (/Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42/libpq.arm) does not match its cputype (7) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (0))
```

I'm compiling again because my compiled files doesn't work with the latest iOS4.2

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
fcntl$UNIX2003 called from function pg_set_noblock in image GlobalScan.
If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first.
```

thanks!

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk

rm -rf  /Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42
mkdir /Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42 #Store there compiled libs
make clean

#Build ARM library
./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --without-readline --disable-ipv6 CC=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/" CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -arch armv6 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT" CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS" LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld
make -C src/interfaces/libpq
cp /Users/montx/Downloads/postgresql-8.4.1/src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a /Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42/libpq.arm


#Build ARM library
./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --without-readline --disable-ipv6 CC=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/" CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -arch armv6 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT" CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS" LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld



#Then build i386 library ==> the simulator is 32bits


CFLAGS="$(OTHER_CFLAGS) -mmacosx-version-min=10.5"
LDFLAGS="$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -mmacosx-version-min=10.5"

make clean && ./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5" && make -C src/interfaces/libpq


cp src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a  /Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42/libpq.i386

#Then make fat binary
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 /Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42/libpq.arm -arch i386 /Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42/libpq.i386 -create -output  /Users/montx/mylibs_sdk42/libpq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me for the arm library but I'm using gcc 4.2 and I'm targeting armv7

```
DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --without-readline --disable-ipv6 \
  CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ \
            -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/" \
  CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -arch armv7 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT" \
  CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS" \
  LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld 
make -C src/interfaces/libpq 
cp src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a lib/libpq.arm
```

My old script for the simulator doesn't work anymore though, and it usto work fine again iOS 3.2.

```
DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer 
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
$ROOT_DIR/configure --host=i386-apple-darwin  \
  CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ \
            -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.5" \
  CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT \
          -mmacosx-version-min=10.5" \
  CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS" \
  LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld

make -C $ROOT_DIR/src/interfaces/libpq
```

**Updated**

Here is the complete script. Drop the bash script in the postgres directory and build. In your project include $POSTGRESDIR/src/include and $POSTGRESDIR/src/interfaces/libpq to get the headers necessary. Note this works for Postgres 8. Haven't tested it on Postgres 9.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -d "./lib" ]
then
    echo "Existing libs deleted"
    rm -rf lib/*
else
    echo "Generating output directory"
    mkdir lib
fi

if [ -e "./src/Makefile.global" ]
then
    make -C ./src/interfaces/libpq distclean
fi

chmod u+x ./configure

#Build i386 library
DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer 
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
./configure --host=i386-apple-darwin  --without-readline --disable-ipv6 \
  CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -mmacosx-version-min=10.5" \
  CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=10.5" \
  CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS" \
  LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld

make -C ./src/interfaces/libpq
cp ./src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a lib/libpq.i386

#Build ARM library
make -C ./src/interfaces/libpq distclean

DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --without-readline --disable-ipv6 \
  CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/" \
  CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -arch armv7 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT" \
  CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS" \
  LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld 
make -C ./src/interfaces/libpq 
cp ./src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a lib/libpq.arm
```

Answer (score 2):

There is project "libpq-ios" on github. I used it.

https://github.com/spacialdb/libpq-ios
http://devcenter.spacialdb.com/iOS.html